# Como iterar en celdas de excel con python

Tags: python, excel, bucles, openpyxl

Tengo problemas para iterar sobre las celdas de columnas en excel para evaluar los valores y asignarle a otra celda el valor correspondiente.
En una hoja de excel, tengo información en 3 columnas, y debo iterar entre los datos de la columna B para encontrar coincidencias en la columna C y agregar el valor de la columna D en la columna A correspondiente al mismo criterio de búsqueda.
Ej:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se muestra el resultado deseado, buscando el valor de la columna C en la columna D, luego se toma el valor de la columna E y se asigna a la columna A. Esto tantas veces como el valor de la columna C se repita.

He intentado iterar entre las columnas C y D pero solo logro iterar los primeros valores (C1 = D1 y C2 = D2) pero no logro que cada valor de la columna C sea comparado con los valores de la columna D.

Este es el código que he usado, pero no he logrado el resultado:

```
    for N in hj.iter_cols(min_col=3, max_col=3):
        N =   hj.cell(row= x, column = 3).value
        for R in hj.iter_cols(min_col=4, max_col=4):
           # if (hj.iter_cols(min_col=3, max_col=3)) == (hj.iter_cols(min_col=4, max_col=4)):
            if N == hj.cell(row= x, column = 4).value:
                hj.cell(row= x, column = 1).value = hj.cell(row= x, column = 5).value
        #hj.cell(row= x, column = 1).value = (hj.iter_cols(min_col=5, max_col=5))
    else:
        next(hj.iter_cols(min_col=3, max_col=3))
```

Comment: ¿Dónde defines el valor de `x`? Es la pieza clave para saber cómo estás iterando por filas.

Comment: el código está mal indentado, el `else` tiene que estar al mismo nivel que el `if` y el segundo `for` no debe estar al interno del primero y yo utilizaría un tercer loop para hacer la comparación entre los valores de `N` y `R`

Comment: @ChemaCortes el valor de x es el resultado de un bucle **for** en donde establezco el rango de celdas que debería recorrer 
``` columna = hj['C']                         
for cell in columna:                           
    Num1 = Num1 + 1      
for x in range(1,Num1):```

Comment: @ArielMontes Gracias por la corrección del indentado del entre el **else** y el **if** ahora en cuanto al segundo **for** intenté dejarlo al mismo nivel del primero y no obtuve resultado. Alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: @Aligtrrz Imagino lo que es `x`, pero no veo como iteras con él. Ya que ése es el problema, que no iteras por filas, el bucle del `x` debería estar en el código que nos presentas tal y como lo tienes.

Comment: Es que te decía de obtener los valores de R de la misma manera en la que obtienes los valores de N con un for al mismo nivel, si funciona en N  funcionará en R. Luego con un tercer for iteras en ambas listas y haces la comparación. Mi idea es que puedas controlar primero el valor en N y el valor en R antes de hacer una confrontación.

Comment: @ArielMontes muchas gracias por la recomendación. de esa forma me funcionó y tuve el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aligtrrz algo que no me queda claro es si los valores en la columna D se pueden repetir y en ese caso, qué índice de fila (el de C o el de D) se usa para tomar el valor de la columna E. Sobre ideas de cómo resolver, si no estás "obligado" a usar listas, una mejor alternativa podría ser usando Numpy o Pandas.

Ambos módulos tienen una función isin() que te ayuda a determinar dónde están todas las ocurrencias de elementos de una colección de datos en otra. Aquí algunos enlaces:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html y
- https://www.pythonpool.com/numpy-isin/.

La respuesta que genera son índices booleanos (ej. [ True False  True False  True]) donde True significa que el elemento existe en esa posición y False, que no existe.